# $\{f\text{ has exactly 1 zero}\}$ is open in $\mathcal{C}^1([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be the subset of $\mathcal{C}^1([0,1])$ (the normed space of $\mathcal{C}^1$ functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, endowed with $||f||=\sup |f|+\sup |f'|$) consisting of all the functions $f$ which are zero in exactly one point $a$ and this point is in $(0,1)$.

It seems clear to me that this set is open. However, I can't seem to prove it.

At first I tried understanding a function $\varphi:\mathcal{C}^1([0,1])\to \mathbb{N}\cup \{-1\}\cup \{\infty\}$ which is defined in the following way:

1. If $f$ has a infinite number of zeros in $(0,1)$, $\varphi(f)=\infty$;
2. Otherwise, if $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$ or $x=1$, $\varphi(f)=-1$;
3. If $f$ is not zero in $\{0,1\}$ and $f$ has a finite number of zeros in $(0,1)$, let $\varphi(f)$ be this number.

Then, since $X=\varphi^{-1}((0.5,1.5))$, if is enough to prove that $\varphi$ is continuous. But I'm not even sure that this is true.

Comment: The map $\varphi$ is not continuous. This can be easily proved by showing that its domain is connected, while its codomain is not.

Comment: @Crostul A continuous function can have connected domain and non-connected codomain. The function's image, on the other hand, is a different story.

Answer (score 4):

Any open neighborhood about $f(x)= (x-0.5)^2$ contains a function of the form $g(x)=(x-0.5)^2+k$ for some non-zero $k$. For positive $k$ this function has no zeroes, and for negative $k$ (sufficiently close to $0$), it has two zeroes.